# Condition number of a product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, condition-number

Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$, is the following inequality
$$\operatorname{cond}(AB) \leq \operatorname{cond}(A)\operatorname{cond}(B),$$ where $\operatorname {cond}$ is the condition number, true?

Is this still true for rectangular matrices?

I know this is true:

> $$||AB|| \leq ||A|| \cdot ||B||$$

The definition of condition number of matrix is as follows:

> $$\operatorname{cond}(A)=||A|| \cdot ||A^{-1}||$$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange if you write your works you will get more attention. (تلاشتون رو برای حل سوال نمایش بدید.)

Comment: How can I type subscript and superscript in formulas?

Comment: Did you test the hypothesis yourself?

Comment: No. For last question you can find your answer in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I ran this code in matlab many times. It's always true.for i=1:10
    b=rand(3);
    a=rand(3);
    [cond(b)*cond(a)    cond(a*b)]
end

Comment: I couldn't find my answer there!

Comment: @Abbas $a^b_c$ is given by `$a^{b}_{c}$`. Both the `^{b}` and the `_{c}` are optional. For further information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Comment: It seems like that It's just true for square Matrices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, the inequality is true for every matrix norm (which satisfies $\|AB\|\le \|A\|\,\|B\|$, by definition.) Indeed,
$$
\operatorname{cond}(AB)=\|AB\|\,\|(AB)^{-1} \| \le \|A\|\,\|B\|\,\|B^{-1}\|\,\|A^{-1} \| =\operatorname{cond}(A)\,\operatorname{cond}(B)
$$
If $A$ and $B$ are non-square, then $A^{-1}$ is not meaningful, and the condition number has to be defined differently. The one definition I know for this case (which agrees with the above when the operator norm is used), is
$$
\operatorname{cond}(A)=\frac{\sigma_1(A)}{\sigma_n(A)} = \frac{\max\{|Ax|:|x|=1\}}{\min \{|Ax| : |x|=1\}}
$$
(Here $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_n$ are the greatest and smallest singular values of $A$, defined in the quotient on the right).
This definition is of interest only when the kernel is trivial. The submultiplicative inequality still holds, because $\sigma_1(AB)\le \sigma_1(A)\sigma_1(B)$ and $\sigma_n(AB)\ge \sigma_n(A)\sigma_n(B) $.

Comment: Thank You. But I'm pretty sure the submultiplicative inequality of condition number doesn't hold for rectangular matrices. Is there a proof for σn(AB)≥σn(A)σn(B)?

Comment: @Abbas For every unit vector $x$, $|Bx|\ge \sigma_n(B)$. Letting $y=Bx$, we get $|Ay|\ge \sigma_n(A) |y|$. Hence, $|ABx|\ge \sigma_n(A)\sigma_n(B)$.

Comment: Hi user103402. How did you conclude this? : $\sigma_n(A)\leq\frac{\|Ay\|}{\|y\|}$ ,(where $y$ is not necessarily a unit vector).
and if we take that for granted we have: $\sigma_n(A).\|Bx||\leq\|ABx\|$ of course we can say $\sigma_n(A).\sigma_n(B)\leq\|ABx\|$ how does it make $\sigma_n(A).\sigma_n(B)\leq \sigma_n(AB)$ possible?

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to clarify this slightly: the reasoning in [user103402's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/551135/19147) isn't quite clear in the case where the matrices are not square, and it can make you think that something false is true as shown in [loup blanc's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2613173/19147).$
\newcommand{\sig}{\operatorname{\sigma}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert #1 \rVert}
$

Let $A \in \R^{m \times n}, B \in \R^{n \times p}$.
Then the question becomes
$$
\operatorname{cond}(AB) = \frac{\sig_1(A B)}{\sig_{\min(m,p)}(A B)}
\stackrel{?}{\le} \frac{\sig_1(A)}{\sig_{\min(m,n)}(A)} \frac{\sig_1(B)}{\sig_{\min(n,p)}(B)} = \operatorname{cond}(A) \operatorname{cond}(B)
.$$
$\sig_1(AB) \le \sig_1(A) \sig_1(B)$ always holds; the question is whether
$$
\sig_{\min(m,p)}(AB) \stackrel{?}{\ge} \sig_{\min(m,n)}(A) \sig_{\min(n,p)}(B)
.$$

If we assume that $m \ge n \ge p$, it holds. We can see this because:

- If $B$ has a nontrivial null space, $\sigma_p(B) = 0$ and the inequality holds trivially. So assume it doesn't.
- In general note that, if $C \in \mathbb R^{q \times r}$ with $q \ge r$, then
  $$
  \sig_r(C)
  = \sqrt{\lambda_{\min}(C^T C)}
  = \sqrt{\inf_{x \in \R^r_*} \frac{x^T C^T C x}{x^T x}}
  = \inf_{x \in \R^r_*} \frac{\norm{C x}}{\norm x}
  $$
  where $\R^r_* = \R^r \setminus \{0\}$.
- Then we can do, because $B x \ne 0$ for $x \ne 0$,
  \begin{align*}
           \sig_p(A B)
      &  = \inf_{x \in \R^p_*} \frac{\norm{A B x}}{\norm x}
    \\&  = \inf_{x \in \R^p_*} \frac{\norm{A B x} \norm{B x}}{\norm{B x} \norm{x}}
    \\&\ge \left( \inf_{x \in \R^p_*} \frac{\norm{A B x}}{\norm{B x}} \right)
           \left( \inf_{x \in \R^p_*} \frac{\norm{B x}}{\norm{x}} \right)
    \\&\ge \left( \inf_{y \in \R^n_*} \frac{\norm{A y}}{\norm{y}} \right)
           \left( \inf_{x \in \R^p_*} \frac{\norm{B x}}{\norm{x}} \right)
    \\&  = \sig_n(A) \sig_p(B)
    .\end{align*}

It holds for $m \le n \le p$ as well by just transposing everything.

But
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
A B = \begin{bmatrix}0\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
A^T B^T = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
gives us a counterexample for both $m \le n \ge p$ and $m \ge n \le p$.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality is false for non-square matrices.

$||.||$ denotes the matricial $2$-norm; if $U\in M_{p,n}\setminus \{0\}$, then we put $cond(U)=||U||||U^+||$ where $U^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $U$.

More precisely, let $\sigma_1\geq \cdots\geq \sigma_k > 0,\cdots,0$ be the singular values of $U$. Then $||U||=\sigma_1,||U^+||=1/\sigma_k$ and (with respect to the definition above) $cond(U)=\sigma_1/\sigma_k$.

Counter-example to $n\not= p,A\in M_{n,p},B\in M_{p,n},cond(AB)\leq cond(A)cond(B)$.

Take $n=2,p=4$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}99&-95.001&-25&76\\99&-95&-25&76\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}10&-62\\-44&-83\\26&9\\-3&88\end{pmatrix}$.

Note that $A$ is ill conditioned.

For more details, see my answer in

[Counter example or proof that $\kappa(AB) \leq \kappa(A)\kappa(B) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897919/counter-example-or-proof-that-kappaab-leq-kappaa-kappab)